# Facebook comment box does not show

Tags: facebook-comments, comments

I am just reading into social plugins and I was trying out the like button and the comment box from facebook. Everything with the like button worked fine and it was easy to set up, but when I tried getting the comment box to work, nothing would show up.

I put the Facebook sdk right after the opening of the body tag as well as tried from what a similar question suggested and put it right before the closing body tag. Neither of these "solutions" helped solve my issue

Some info about my site, it is local for testing purposes.

and in case you need my html for the page here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="language" content="english"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">

    <title>ATCC BPA</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="site2.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=13855310161";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


    <div id="container">

      <h1 id="header">
        Alexandria Technical and Community College<br>
        Business Professionals of America<br>
        2012-2013
      </h1>

      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="members.html">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="officers.html">Officers</a></li>
        <li><a href="torch.html">Torch</a></li>
        <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="photos.htlm">Photos</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="content">
        <p>
          Text can go here about your page <br/>
          about anything going on, and can even incorperate a facebook comment section.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.alextechbpa.com" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>


      <div id="footer">
        <span id="email">email</span> 
        <span id="facebook">
          <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=www.alextechbpa.com" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
          </iframe>
        </span>
      </div><!-- end footer div-->

      </div><!-- end #container-->
    </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks for any advice or help anyone can provide me with! Any additional info I will do my best to provide!

Comment: According to a WHOIS service I asked, the domain “alextechbpa.com” is not even registered.

Comment: Does it need be? I thought i would be able to fill in any value and it wouldn't matter. Cause from the description on Facebook it made it seem like it is just to post a post-back URL on Facebook